# How to use requests to crawl the project list information of kickstarter？

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I want to crawl the project list information of kickstarter(https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology).I used the developer tool to obtain project information, as shown in the following figure 1[image][image].I used Python and requests to send requests to this link, but the returned file was not the corresponding JSON file.The code of my crawler is shown below. What should I do to obtain project related JSON files?

```
import requests
import json

headers={xxx}
cookies={xxx}
def get_data(url):
    url = 'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?google_chrome_workaround&category_id=7&woe_id=0&sort=magic&seed=2806592&page={}'
    response = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_str)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_data()
```

Comment: Consider using [beatifulsoup4](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. beatifulsoup4 is a good tool for extracting tag content, but it is significantly less efficient than parsing json files. So I would like to try to see if I can get the json file directly

Comment: Request it and use python's built in json library to parse it.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp